# Understanding passage from Scarlet Letter about "keeping with the scene"?

Tags: nathaniel-hawthorne, the-scarlet-letter

I am reading this part of the Scarlet Letter in the Custom House:

> It would be too much in keeping with the scene to excite surprise, were we to look about us and discover a form, beloved, but gone hence, now sitting quietly in a streak of this magic moonshine, with an aspect that would make us doubt whether it had returned from afar, or had never once stirred from our fireside.

I did not understand the initial part:

> It would be too much in keeping with the scene to excite surprise

I could understand after that, which was saying how we would discover a beloved creature that would be close or really far.

**However, I don't understand this the expression of "It would be too much in  keeping with the scene to excite surprise"?**

---

I've been using [Sparknotes "No Fear Literature" tool that simplifies passages from *The Scarlet Literature*](http://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/lit/the-scarlet-letter/the-custom-house/page_15.html). It interprets the quote

> An entire class of susceptibilities, and a gift connected with them,—of no great richness or value, but the best I had,—was gone from me.

as this:

> My writing gift might not have been very rich or valuable, but it was the best I had, and it was gone

How could that be if writing is not even mentioned? He mentions "an entire class of susceptibilities."

Comment: The Scarlet Letter is already written in modern English. What do you mean by translation?

Comment: I am following this website: http://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/lit/the-scarlet-letter/the-custom-house/page_15.html. I read the book and then consult that site to check I understood everything. I am trying to force myself to gain a better understanding of 1800s texts.

Comment: Translation isn't the best word to use here. Try "what does this passage mean".

Comment: It means "it would fit the scene too well to surprise anyone".

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm not entirely sure what advice to give here. I edited the question and removed my downvote, not sure why others haven't done the same. I do think that using the sparknotes' "translation" is the wrong way to go. The problem with such a "translation" is that it gives you an answer without giving you the process of finding an answer. So using such a tool doesn't give you good practice with interpreting a passage yourself; it only gives you practice trying to see how the wording of the original corresponds with sparknote's interpretation.

Comment: @Hamlet I feel like using the spark notes guide is better than not using it. For example, if I had read "An entire class of susceptibilities, and a gift connected with them,—of no great richness or value, but the best I had,—was gone from me." I wouldn't have understood and just skipped it and kept going. However, the issue now is that even when reading the spark notes I don't understand how that sentence could possibly mean what the spark notes says

Comment: My suggestions are as follows. (1) it's perfectly fine if you don't understand *everything* in a book. With some of the books I read, I'll have to reread the same book multiple times before I even come close to grasping everything. So instead of trying to read *Scarlet Letter* once and get everything, it might be preferable to read it one time to grasp some of the details, and then reread it a second time, when you have a better sense of the overall plot and more of a feel for the language, to learn about the details you missed the first time.

Comment: (2) that's my only suggestion. I was going to suggest that if you feel like you can't understand anything, that you might want to consider reading a few short stories by Hawthorne or his contemporaries to get some practice before tackling a longer novel. But after thinking about it, my guess is that (1) is the best option.

Comment: @Hamelt what short stories do you recommend for a beginner?

Comment: @Pablo doesn't matter. I'm pretty sure Hawthorne has several short stories. The point is that they'll be short, and thus easier.

Comment: What was obscure about the first passage? Was the expression "in keeping with" unfamiliar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is somewhat convoluted, obviously. You have to peel back the layers like an onion's.

Let's start with the "form, beloved." The writer loved someone, but she has "gone hence," so she has moved away (but may return "from afar"). Now he feels haunted by her, so much so that he imagines her sitting by the fire as if she'd never left. The ghostly simile is extended with the ray of moonlight (and implies that it's dark).

But we're in the writer's present. He must invite us to "look about" a room, or "scene," to see the ghost. "In keeping with," in this context, means *consistent,* that is, a ghost would fit into the atmosphere of this room. The sense of this first clause is so convoluted because it depends on inversion. We are *not* surprised to see a ghost because it is *too* consistent.

From the context, however, it appears the narrator is only describing his late nights. There is no woman. He has given us this brief tableau to evoke a sense of longing and mystery.

In the other sentence, "susceptibilities" refers to the inspiration the narrator feels he should get from his surroundings at the Custom House, because he gets inspiration from the same sources anywhere else. He has just used several paragraphs (which include the first sentence) to tell us about that inspiration. In other words, he is *susceptible* to seeing images in moonlight, which he then writes about during the day.

Comment: Your explanation is outstanding